# How to have a changing background on a menu depending on selected item

Tags: css, menubar

This is daunting me and I can't see the way to go.  This is the first time I put a question here, so correct me if I´m not following protocol. Thanks!!!

I need the background of the menu to change according to the selected item so when active, the items to the left will show in orange while keeping the items on the right in gray.

Also, the triangle separating the colors have to keep to the right of the active menu item.

For the first element, is easy, but the second and forward, I cant make the code work as it cuts on the boundaries of the menu.

For example, I have [individuos] [empresas] [corredores] [proveedores]

When empresas is active, individuos and empresas should be orange while corredores and provedores should be gray.

If corredores is selected, then individuos, empresas and corredores should be orange while proveedores is gray.

I wanted to post an image to illustrate but as newbie I am not allowed.

```
#navigation {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 210px;
  width: 730px;
  background-color: #757373;
}

#navigation ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 40px 0 10px;
}

#navigation .empresas .active {
  background: url(images/the-background.png) no-repeat right;
}
```

This one is good
[image: First active element appears correctly]

This one is not, see that INDIVIDUOS should be orange
[image: Second element is missing orange on the left for first element]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THE SOLUTION**
Ok, problem solved and it was the cleanest trick I´ve seen. I did not need to add anything else to the php, classes or the like. The solution was pointed by a colleague. All that it was needed was some trickery with z-index and positioning. Thank @peter and @PeterSmith for your input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Ejemplo menú</title>

<style type="text/css">

ul { list-style-type: none; }

ul li { display: inline; position: absolute; text-align: right; }

a { position: absolute; }

.uno { border: 1px #FF6600 solid; z-index: 4; width: 100px; }
a.uno:hover { background: #FF6600; }

.dos { border: 1px #FF6600 solid; z-index: 3; width: 200px; }
a.dos:hover { background: #FF6600; }

.tres { border: 1px #FF6600 solid; z-index: 2; width: 300px; }
a.tres:hover { background: #FF6600; }

.cuatro { border: 1px #FF6600 solid; z-index: 1; width: 400px; }
a.cuatro:hover { background: #FF6600; }

</style>

</head>

<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="" class="uno">PRUEBA 1</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="dos">PRUEBA 2</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="tres">PRUEBA 3</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="cuatro">PRUEBA 4</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you mark your own answer as accepted so it will not show up anymore in the unansered section?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/6dX6k/) provides some inspiration?

CSS:

```
#navigation li {
    background-color: #ffa500;
}
#navigation li.active+li,
#navigation li.active+li+li,
#navigation li.active+li+li+li,
#navigation li.active+li+li+li+li,
#navigation li.active+li+li+li+li+li {
    background-color: #757373;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">professionals</a></li>
        <li><a href="">organizations</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="">others</a></li>
        <li><a href="">others2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Update**

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/6dX6k/3/) with the "arrow" and more. If you want this to work also in IE7, then add `span` elements instead of using `:before` and `:after`.

Comment: I have attached images to clarify problem and modified the menu items names so it all matches

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, I´m trying to see the example but the gray box stays between others and others2

Comment: @MAGA: Try the run command. Or try [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/6dX6k/5/) or [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/6dX6k/4/).

Comment: Nope, no good, I see the menu, but when I click on it, it returns the same... Using chrome and firefox 4

Comment: @MAGA Aaaah! Clicking on such link normally would result in loading a new page. In thát page, you set the `active` class to the other list item. I assumed you did it that way already because you used `.active` instead of `:active`. In short: this is not going to work for `:active` nor for `:focus`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just saw your latest comment below about the .active class.

If you can add some javascript to your pages, you could run through a for loop for each li item, appending "orange" to its class, until you find the .active class, then the rest would have "grey" appended to the class. I'll try a fiddler later when I've got some free time

Comment: Yes, this is strictly html+css.  Hmm, with PHP and adding classes .grey and .orange would have been a solution. The thing is that the menu is dynamically generated (Drupal) but I was hoping to make it work from CSS only.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with how Drupal creates menus. Does it add any special class or id to the current page item in the nav? Also, a link to the site would help troubleshooting

Comment: The thing is that this is all the root menu, meaning, no childs.  I have the usual. a class for the menu bar: #navigation as shown on the code and then each tab has a class: .menu-114 and so on.  Also, I get classes for .active, .first, .last, .active-trail.  The thing is that since this is all root menu, then I dont have trails and the like generated.